# Intent filter when audio recording starts

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, audiorecord

Does there exist an intent filter which indicates when audio recording starts, or will I have to create one? I am building an app that records in a background thread, and I want the activity to be updated when the recording starts or stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by broadcasting an intent I generated.